# how to create similarity matrix in numpy python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning

I have data in a file in following form:

```
user_id, item_id, rating
1, abc,5
1, abcd,3
2, abc, 3
2, fgh, 5
```

So, the matrix I want to form for above data is following:

```
#   itemd_ids
# abc  abcd  fgh
[[5,    3,    0]  # user_id 1
 [3,    0,    5]] # user_id 2
```

where missing data is replaced by 0.

But from this I want to create both user to user similarity matrix and item to item similarity matrix?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, this is not a programming problem but a math problem. But I think you better off using variance-covariance matrix. Or correlation matrix, if the scale of the values are very different, say, instead of having:

```
>>> x
array([[5, 3, 0],
       [3, 0, 5],
       [5, 5, 0],
       [1, 1, 7]])
```

You have:

```
>>> x
array([[5, 300, 0],
       [3, 0, 5],
       [5, 500, 0],
       [1, 100, 7]])
```

To get a variance-cov matrix:

```
>>> np.cov(x)
array([[  6.33333333,  -3.16666667,   6.66666667,  -8.        ],
       [ -3.16666667,   6.33333333,  -5.83333333,   7.        ],
       [  6.66666667,  -5.83333333,   8.33333333, -10.        ],
       [ -8.        ,   7.        , -10.        ,  12.        ]])
```

Or the correlation matrix:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(x)
array([[ 1.        , -0.5       ,  0.91766294, -0.91766294],
       [-0.5       ,  1.        , -0.80295507,  0.80295507],
       [ 0.91766294, -0.80295507,  1.        , -1.        ],
       [-0.91766294,  0.80295507, -1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

This is the way to look at it, the diagonal cell, i.e., `(0,0)` cell, is the correlation of your 1st vector in X to it self, so it is 1. The other cells, i.e, `(0,1)` cell, is the correlation between the 1st and 2nd vector in X. They are negatively correlated. Or similarly, the 1st and 3rd cell are positively correlated.

covariance matrix or correlation matrix avoid the zero problem pointed out by @Akavall.

Comment: I think covariance approach is better than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [What's the fastest way in Python to calculate cosine similarity given sparse matrix data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat)

Having:

```
A = np.array(
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

dist_out = 1-pairwise_distances(A, metric="cosine")
dist_out
```

Result in:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.40824829,  0.40824829],
       [ 0.40824829,  1.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.40824829,  0.33333333,  1.        ]])
```

But that works for dense matrix. For sparse you have to develop your solution.