# Compute Pairwise Cosine Similarity using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am new to this, so it would be helpful if someone could point me in right direction/help me with some tutorial.
Given a sentence and a list of other sentences (English):

```
s = "This concept of distance is not restricted to two dimensions."
list_s = ["It is not difficult to imagine the figure above translated into three dimensions.", "We can persuade ourselves that the measure of distance extends to an arbitrary number of dimensions;"]
```

I want to compute pairwise cosine similarity between each sentence in the list and sentence s, then find the max value.

What i've got so far:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2', min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=True, tokenizer=tokenize)
bow_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform([s, ' '.join(list_s)])
```

## 1. What's next?

## 2. Should we transform the whole corpus or just 2 sentences when compute pairwise cosine similarity?

## 3. How to apply removing stopwords and stemming for this?

## Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to transform your documents as follows

```
X = tfidf.fit_transform([s] + list_s) # now X will have 3 rows
```

1. What's next?: you have to find cosine similarity between each row of tf-idf matrix. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat) on how to do that. For intuition, you can calculate distance between `s` and `list_s` using `cosine` distance.

   ```
   from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
   cosine(X[0].toarray(), X[1].toarray()) # cosine between s and 1st sentence
   ```
2. I would suggest transform whole corpus to tf-idf matrix since the model will also generate vocabulary i.e. you vector will correspond to this dictionary. You shouldn't transform only 2 sentences.
3. You can remove stopwords by adding `stop_words='english'` when you create tf-idf model (i.e. `tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(..., stop_words='english')`).

For stemming, you might consider `nltk` in order to create a stemmer. Here is a simple way to stem your texts. (note that you might want to remove punctuation before stemming also)

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem(text):
    text_stem = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in text.split(' ')]
    text_stem_join = ' '.join(text_stem)
    return text_stem_join

list_s_stem = list(map(stem, list_s)) # map stem function to list of documents
```

Now, you can use this `list_s_stem` in `TfidfVectorizer` instead of `list_s`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i want, i used your code and have another question:  
1. cosine(...) or 1-(cosine) is correct? 
2. Even if i changed the first sentence in the list_s by s, it's mean cosine(X[0], X[1]) should be = 1 because we're comparing a sentence with itself. But it doesn't. Can you help me figure out? Thanks!

Comment: you can use either cosine or 1-cosine. cosine will measure how similar documents are. 1-cosine is basically distance between two documents (cosine distance). For second question, cosine(X[0], X[0]) will compare `s` with `s`, i.e. `X[0], X[1], X[2]` are tf-idf transformation of `s, list_s[0], list_s[1]` respectively.