# Calculate cosine similarity of all possible text pairs retrieved from 4 mysql tables

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, text-mining, cosine-similarity

I have 4 tables with schema (app, text_id, title, text). Now I'd like to compute the cosine similarity between all possible text pairs (title & text concatenated) and store them eventually in a csv file with fields (app1, app2, text_id1, text1, text_id2, text2, cosine_similarity).

Since there are a lot of possible combinations it should run quite efficient. What is the most common approach here? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Edit:
Although the provided reference might touch my problem, I still cant figure out how to approach this. Could someone provide more details on the strategy to accomplish this task? Next to the calculated cosine similarity I need also the corresponding text pairs as an output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way in Python to calculate cosine similarity given sparse matrix data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a minimal example to calculate the pairwise cosine similarities between a set of documents (assuming you have successfully retrieved the title and text from your database).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Assume thats the data we have (4 short documents)
data = [
    'I like beer and pizza',
    'I love pizza and pasta',
    'I prefer wine over beer',
    'Thou shalt not pass'
]

# Vectorise the data
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(data) # `X` will now be a TF-IDF representation of the data, the first row of `X` corresponds to the first sentence in `data`

# Calculate the pairwise cosine similarities (depending on the amount of data that you are going to have this could take a while)
S = cosine_similarity(X)

'''
S looks as follows:
array([[ 1.        ,  0.4078538 ,  0.19297924,  0.        ],
       [ 0.4078538 ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.19297924,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])

The first row of `S` contains the cosine similarities to every other element in `X`. 
For example the cosine similarity of the first sentence to the third sentence is ~0.193. 
Obviously the similarity of every sentence/document to itself is 1 (hence the diagonal of the sim matrix will be all ones). 
Given that all indices are consistent it is straightforward to extract the corresponding sentences to the similarities.
'''
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. Based on that I have another two questions:
First, I need to iterate through the array and check where the cosine is >= 0.8 and then I need to somehow get the document pairs (not only the position in the array, but also the name of the documents). How would you do this?
Second, I have a lot of data, therefore computation cost is an issue. Is it possible to calculate only half of the matrix, since its anyway symmetric?

Comment: @EmanuelGeorge you can get the indices from `S` by either doing `np.where(S>=0.8)` or by thresholding the whole array by doing `S[S<0.8] = 0`, which sets all elements with a sim<=0.8 to 0. A single entry in `S` represents the similarity between a pair of documents (index 0/1) is the similarity between document 0 and document 1). If you have list with document names than a mapping from S to the list of document names is straightforward. `sklearn` is very efficient, I don't think it will calculate anything twice.