# Iterate pandas rows and compute cosine distance between rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, trigonometry

I want to compute cosine distance between each rows in a pandas dataframe. Before computing the distance, i want to select only elements in vectors which are > 0 and intersects (have values in both rows). For example, row1 [0,1,45,0,0] and row2 [4,11,2,0,0]. in this case, the program will only compute cosine distance between [1,45] and [11,2]. Here is my script, but this takes a long time to complete. Any help on simplifying the script and reducing processing time is appreciated.

```
data = df.values
m, k = data.shape
dist = np.zeros((m, m))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(i,m):
        if i!=j:
            vec1 = data[i,:]
            vec2 = data[j,:]
            pairs = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(vec1, vec2) if x > 0 and y > 0]
            if pairs:
                sub_list_1, sub_list_2 = map(list, zip(*pairs))
                dist[i][j] = dist[j][i]=cosine(sub_list_1, sub_list_2)
            else:
                dist[i][j]= dist[j][i] =1
        else:
            dist[i][j]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`cosine docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine) we have the following info -

**scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u, v)** : Computes the Cosine distance between 1-D arrays.

The Cosine distance between `u` and `v`, is defined as

[image]

where `u⋅v` is the dot product of `u` and `v`.

Using the above formula, we would have one vectorized solution using [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
def self_cosine_vectorized(a):
    dots = a.dot(a.T)
    sqrt_sums = np.sqrt((a**2).sum(1))
    cosine_dists = 1 - (dots/sqrt_sums)/sqrt_sums[:,None]
    np.fill_diagonal(cosine_dists,0)
    return cosine_dists
```

Thus, to get `dist` -

```
dist = self_cosine_vectorized(df.values)
```

**Runtime test and verification**

Original approach :

```
def original_app(data):
    m, k = data.shape
    dist = np.zeros((m, m))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(m):
            if i!=j:
                vec1 = data[i,:]
                vec2 = data[j,:]
                pairs = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(vec1, vec2) if x > 0 and y > 0]
                if pairs:
                    sub_list_1, sub_list_2 = map(list, zip(*pairs))
                    dist[i][j] = cosine(sub_list_1, sub_list_2)
                else:
                    dist[i][j]
            else:
                dist[i][j]=0 
    return dist
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [203]: data = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [204]: np.allclose(original_app(data), self_cosine_vectorized(data))
Out[204]: True

In [205]: %timeit original_app(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 813 ms per loop

In [206]: %timeit self_cosine_vectorized(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [208]: 813000.0/101
Out[208]: 8049.504950495049
```

Crazy **`8000x+`** speedup there!

Comment: this calculates the distance between the 'whole' 2 vectors, but does not answer my question (For example, vector1 [0,1,45,0,0] and vector2 [4,11,2,0,0]. in this case, the program will only compute cosine distance between [1,45] and [11,2]. )

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin So, the code that you have listed in the question isn't working in the first place?

Comment: it is running forever, as i have a large dataframe ( 1877 x 6516). it works with a smaller dataframe though..

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin Well I meant in theory is your code giving you the correct results that is if given some minimal sample data, would your code in the question give you the correct result?

Comment: yes, given a smaller size of dataframe, the code produces correct results..

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin Well then I am not sure where is the confusion. Added a sample large test data to verify against your working loopy version.

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin Did the updates satisfy your needs?

Comment: sorry, your solution did not answer the question. the issue is not on computing cosine distance for whole dataframe (solutions are available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat)). As i specified in my first comment, i want to filter out zeroes from both vectors (based on their index) before computing their similarity/distance; see example above

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin Well in your first comment you said - `For example, vector1 [0,1,45,0,0] and vector2 [4,11,2,0,0]. in this case, the program will only compute cosine distance between [1,45] and [11,2].` So, if you are only filter out zeros, then you should have [4,11,2] and not [11,2], right? Also, I asked you earlier twice if your loopy code is working, to which you confirmed that it does work

Comment: "filter out zeroes from both vectors (**based on their index**)" => vector1 has values > 0 at indexes 1,2 [1,45] and the values on vector2 on these indexes are [11,2].