# Calculating cosine similarity: ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

hope everyone's well. I'm trying to use the following method to efficiently calculate cosine similarity of a (29805, 40) sparse matrix, created by HashingVectorizing (Sklearn) my dataset. The method below is originally from @Waylon Flinn's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat) question.

```
def cosine_sim(A):

    similarity = np.dot(A, A.T)

    # squared magnitude of preference vectors (number of occurrences)
    square_mag = np.diag(similarity)

    # inverse squared magnitude
    inv_square_mag = 1 / square_mag

    # if it doesn't occur, set it's inverse magnitude to zero (instead of inf)
    inv_square_mag[np.isinf(inv_square_mag)] = 0

    # inverse of the magnitude
    inv_mag = np.sqrt(inv_square_mag)

    # cosine similarity (elementwise multiply by inverse magnitudes)
    cosine = similarity * inv_mag
    return cosine.T * inv_mag
```

When I try with a dummy matrix, everything works fine.

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10000, 100)).astype(float)
cos_sim = cosine_sim(A)
```

but when I try with my own matrix..

```
cos_sim = cosine_sim(sparse_matrix)
```

I get

```
ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d.
```

Now, calling .shape on my matrix returns (29805, 40). How is that not 2-d? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? The error occurs here (from jupyter notebook traceback):

```
----> 6     square_mag = np.diag(similarity)
```

Thanks for reading! For context, calling sparse_matrix returns this

```
<29805x40 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 1091384 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: `numpy` functions (and others) are not 'sparse' aware.  Often they try to convert the inputs to arrays, with a `np.asarray(sparse_matrix)` - try that yourself with your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.diag` starts with

```
 v = asanyarray(v)
```

`similarity = np.dot(A, A.T)` works with `A` sparse, because it delegates the action to the sparse matrix multiplication.  The result will be a `sparse` matrix - you can check that yourself.

But then try to pass that to `np.asanyarray`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while typing out the question, I tried converting to an [ndarray object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html) and it worked. Still posting the question and the answer, it might help someone else. Cheers!

Solution:

```
cos_sim = cosine_sim(sparse_matrix.A)
```