# Sparse MATRIX - Error TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

good night!

I'm trying to create a sparse array with a Pandas dataframe, but the error below appears.
How can I solve this?

treino_df.dtypes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGIl.png)

I think the problem lies in the fact that some variables are not int (but object)

```
if os.path.isfile('matriz_esparsa_treino.npz'):
    matriz_esparsa_treino = sparse.load_npz('matriz_esparsa_treino.npz')
    print("Matriz Carregada.")

else: 
    matriz_esparsa_treino = sparse.csr_matrix((treino_df.Nota.values, (treino_df.ID_Usuario.values, 
                                                                                 treino_df.ID_Produto.values)))
    print('Matriz Criada. O shape é: (user, movie): ', matriz_esparsa_treino.shape)
    sparse.save_npz("dados/matriz_esparsa_treino.npz", matriz_esparsa_treino)
    print('Matriz Salva em Disco.')
```

Comment: Use a categorical encoding like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158157/how-to-go-from-a-tsv-with-feature-list-strings-to-a-csr-matrix-in-python/67164799

Comment: The arrays passed to `csr_matrix` should have numeric values.  Strings in pandas object dtype columns don't work.