# Cosine Similarity for Sentences in Dataframe

Tags: cosine-similarity

I have a data frame which has two columns. The content column has about 8000 rows of sentences. The embeddings column has the embedding for each sentence from the content column.

[image]

I want to get the cosine similarity score for each pair of sentences.

I used: cosine_similarity
(df['embeddings'][0],
df['embeddings'][1:]
)
However, it only gives me the cosine similarity matrix between the sentence 0 and the rest sentences.

What I want is a dataframe like:

[image]
Any hints will be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Might be a good idea to tag your question with Pandas or Python just to get some more attention on it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the cosine similarity of every combination of 2 sentences in the data frame.

This can be done using the [`itertools.combinations` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

sentenceCombs = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Sentence0', 'Sentence1', 'CosineSim'])
idx = 0;
for comb in combinations(df.columns, 2):
   s0 = comb[0]
   s1 = comb[1]
   sentenceCombs.loc[idx] = [s0, s1, cosine_similarity(s0, s1)]
```

This code is untested, but with some modification (and a delimiter that definitely doesn't appear in your dataset), it should work well.

Comment: Hey luke, thank you so much for your feedback. For the line df.apply(lambda x: x.append('SUPERSUPER'),1), it shows "cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

Comment: edited, try that. The code is still untested, it may be easier for you to read the summary of what it's intended to do and use my code as a starting point.

Comment: Also, @KaylaWentingJiang, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much, luke! I used this line and it worked: df['content_delim'] =  df['content'].astype(str) + delim. I am having another error when I was trying to split the sentence:  s0 = sentences[0]
   s1 = sentences[1]
   sentenceCombs.loc[idx] = [s0, s1, cosine_similarity(s0, s1)]. It said the comb which is a tuple "'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'".

Comment: My Bad! I thought that the combiantions module returned strings, not tuples, so that makes this problem much, much easier! I'll edit the answer

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance, luke! It worked very well. :-).

Comment: Glad I could help @LikeCoding :). If the answer is finished, it's a good idea to set it as the accepted answer and upvote.